# Word needed for "checking with additional data / method results"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a word that describes

> validating or non-validating a result of a research by cross checking
>   with some additional (new) data or using a another method to see if we
>   have been right

I think to use the word "cross validation", but unfortunately that is already used by a very specific technique in statistics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation and since I need the word in a research context, it might easily be misunderstood to refer to the statistical technique.

Example sentence:

> The statistical machine would provide a multivariable /
>   mutli-dimensional cross validation.

Comment: Sounds like simple *validation* or *verification*. Why does the word need to be more specific and in what way?

Comment: @macraf : An expert looks at the data and makes an assessment. I shall build a statistical model/machine one the data and the assessment. The model/machine provide an additional "assessment" which would *together* with the expert's opinion give a better assessment of the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a phrase that was included in the question - [Cross-Check](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cross-check?q=cross%20check):

> Verify (figures or information) by using an alternative source or method:
>   '*always try to cross-check your bearings*'
>
> (as noun **cross-checking**) '*no cross-checking has been done*'

The wikipedia page on cross-validation does not include 'cross-check' on it; the dictionary definition does not appear to indicate it as a recognised synonym for the statistical technique. The [wikipedia disambiguation page for cross check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_check) includes references to hockey and chess but not statistics. It therefore seems unlikely to cause the possible confusion that might arise from the use of the phrase 'cross validation', in this context.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like [substantiate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/substantiate) or [corroborate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/corroborate)? Or maybe even both. You substantiated your claim with corroborating evidence.